# Do multiple search and replaces in PHP string?

Tags: php

I am working with PHP and WordPress right now, I need to basically run the below code to Replace text in `$current_path` with the text in `$new_path` if `$current_path` EXIST in `$content`

I would prefer to be able to iterate over an array instead of running this over and over like this, or any better method would be nice?

```
$content = 'www.domain.com/news-tag/newstaghere'

$current_path = 'test-tag';
$new_path = 'test/tag';
$content = str_replace($current_path, $new_path, $content);

$current_path = 'news-tag';
$new_path = 'news/tag';
$content = str_replace($current_path, $new_path, $content);

$current_path = 'ppc-tag';
$new_path = 'ppc/tag';
$content = str_replace($current_path, $new_path, $content);
```

Comment: check: arrays using in http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`str_replace()` accepts array arguments](http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php):

```
$current_paths = array('test-tag','news-tag','ppc-tag');
$new_paths = array('test/tag','news/tag','ppc/tag');
$new_content = str_replace($current_paths, $new_paths, $content);
```

Or you can use a single array with [`strtr()`](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.strtr.php):

```
$path_map = array('test-tag'=>'test/tag', 'news-tag'=>'news/tag', 'ppc-tag'=>'ppc/tag');
$new_content = strtr($content, $path_map);
```

However, you seem to be doing something very generic. Maybe all you need is a regex?

```
$new_content = preg_replace('/(test|news|ppc)-(tag)/u', '\1/\2', $content);
```

Or maybe even just

```
$new_content = preg_replace('/(\w+)-(tag)/u', '\1/\2', $content);
```

Answer (score 2):

```
$content = 'www.domain.com/news-tag/newstaghere'

$current_paths = array('test-tag','news-tag','ppc-tag');
$new_paths = array('test/tag','news/tag','ppc/tag';
$content = str_replace($current_paths, $new_paths, $content);
```

Answer (score 0):

Array arguments can be provided for the str_replace function, as noted on the following PHP.net page:
http://php.net/manual/en/function.str-replace.php

Please see "Example #2" on the page linked above for details.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that:

```
$content = 'www.domain.com/news-tag/newstaghere';
$content = preg_replace('~www\.domain\.com/\w++\K-(?=tag/)~', '/', $content);
```